# Determine Active Node in SQL Failover Cluster

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, failover

Does anyone know how to determine the active node of a SQL Active-Passive Failover Cluster programmatically from T-SQL?

`@@SERVERNAME` only returns the virtual server name, which is identical from both nodes.

I don't plan to make any decisions based on the data - I trust the failover to do its thing - but I would like to include the information in an event log so I can tell which node in the cluster was active when the event occurred, or help determine if exceptions come up as a result of a failover.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
Select ServerProperty('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')
```

Comment: If your driver can't handle it directly, convert it to a varchar: `SELECT convert(varchar(100), ServerProperty('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS'))`

Comment: Note that according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) you should be using `MachineName` rather than `ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS` for fail over clusters. Tested both values on a HA group and a standalone instance in each case it worked as expected but I assume there is some reason they recommend one over the other.

Comment: I'm willing to bet there might be a difference with VMs.

Comment: I've expanded the answer. In my case (SQL2008R2) `MachineName` returns the network name associated with the instance, not the node. `ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS` returns the actual node name. If you're with SQL 2012 and on, better use the [dmv sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187341%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This works in newer versions:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_virtualservernodes();
```

full details at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-virtualservernodes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes;
```

full details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-cluster-nodes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this checks if Server is the Primary server in the Availability Group and then based on this condition do X:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ars.role FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars JOIN sys.availability_groups ag ON ars.group_id = ag.group_id WHERE ars.role_desc = 'PRIMARY')
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'PRIMARY' -- DO STUFF IF PRIMARY
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'NOT PRIMARY' --- DON'T DO STUFF
    END
```

Comment: Thanks Gozzy, this works great. Is there any reason the query could not be simplified as SELECT * FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states WHERE role_desc = 'PRIMARY'?